# Active Directory with LDAP is not returning employeeID attribute

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I am working on a project which needs ADS integration. I have developed application using java.

I am trying to connect to ADS using LDAP, the same is working fine. It is returning many attributes like (samAccountName, email, givenName etc.) but it is not returning attribute **employeeID** which is crucial attribute in my application.

Here is the code which I wrote to fetch user attributes.

```
private static DirContext ldapContext;
  private static String LDAP_URL = "ldap://192.168.10.101:3268";
  private static String SECURITY_AUTH = "simple";
  private static String CTXT_FACTORY = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";

  public ADSService() {
  }


  public static void fetchEmployees(String username, String password){
        try
        {
          Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>(11);
          ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, CTXT_FACTORY);
          ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, LDAP_URL);
          ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, SECURITY_AUTH);
          ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username );
          ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
          DirContext ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);
          int count = 0;

          // Create the search controls         
          SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();

          //Specify the attributes to return
          String returnedAtts[]={"sn","givenName", "samAccountName", "mail", "employeeID"};
          searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);

          //Specify the search scope
          searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

          //specify the LDAP search filter
          String searchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user))";

          //Specify the Base for the search
          //String searchBase = "dc=dom,dc=fr";
          //initialize counter to total the results
          int totalResults = 0;
          String searchBase = "dc=in,dc=corp,dc=orgname,dc=com";
          // Search for objects using the filter
          NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ldapContext.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);

          //Loop through the search results
          while (answer.hasMoreElements())
          {
            SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();      
            Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
            count++;
            if (attrs != null)
            {
                NamingEnumeration ne = attrs.getAll();
                while (ne.hasMore())
                {
                  Attribute attr = (Attribute) ne.next();
                  System.out.println("Attribute  :: " + attr);

                }
                ne.close();
              }
          }

        }catch(NamingException ne){
            ne.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Please help me to get **employeeID** attribute

Comment: Are you sure it exists and has a value? You can try to view your directory with some LDAP editing tools (e.g. www.ldapadministrator.com)  and compare with your output.

Comment: Yes it exists, I checked the same using Power Shell. Does LDAP restricts some of the attributes as claimed in following link? [link] https://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/help/csv-import-management/active-directory-ldap-attributes.html

Comment: The link doesn't claim anything, moreover it referred to a third party software  and not LDAP. Share your PS code (or compare it with your java code). If attribute is used and has a value then it should work in PS and java.